# Is it possible to set stand-by database to active, do changes and then continue restore chain?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore, log-shipping

Basically, I'm using a custom log shipping method on a sql 2012, where the transaction files are manually copied to an offsite location. The files are then restored using something similar:

```
RESTORE LOG xyz
    FROM MyAdvWorks_log2
    WITH STANDBY = 'c:\undo.bak'
```

I would really like to be able to set that stand-by database briefly to Active, do various stuff (not just read) and then rollback/discard those changes and allow the restore to continue.

Is that even possible?
If not, can I copy the stand-by server and set it to active (and then when I'm done, delete it)?

Comment: No. In the situation you describe, as soon as you make the database writable, to revert you would have to start the restore process over again. If all you're doing is making changes you're going to roll back, why not make a separate copy? Or do that in a transaction on the source?

Comment: How about copying the read only db, attaching it somewhere else and doing the restore to make it active. Then throw the whole lot of that away? Meanwhile the orignal stays in log shipping.

Comment: @JamesRyan that sounds like a plan. However, how do I copy the database? I tried detaching, copy, but I can't attach. It says: Cannot attach a database that was being restored
Any suggestions?

Comment: @RuvanFernando - Do not try to detach the restoring database. You can get a usable database by restoring the backup and logs (up the to current point) of the **active** database.  Finish with RECOVER and use the database for your activity, then drop the database when you are finished. The biggest issue is: "How long does it take to restore your database?" 10 minutes? 10 hours? It will make a difference in your strategy.

Comment: Are you using enterprise or standard version of SQL server. Enterprise has database snapshots that will suit your needs.

Comment: Enterprise. @Kin how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

*(since this is longer than a comment .. so posting this as an answer)*

In sql server enterprise edition, you can leverage database snapshots.

If I understand your question, you want to do some changes on a standy (not live) copy of your database and then discard those ?

If that is true, then you can create a database snapshot of your main database using :

```
CREATE DATABASE snapshotDBName... AS SNAPSHOT OF yourPRODDBNAME
```

Then do the modifications - Inserts / Updates / Deletes using regular TSQL and once you are done with your modifications, you can drop the snapshot using

```
DROP DATABASE snapshotDBName
```

You can read more on [SQL Server Database Snapshots](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-2005-snapshots/)

**Note**: If this is not what you want, then I will delete this answer .. which I wrote assuming stuff.

Comment: I presume this is to happen at the Master (active) database? Is is possible to transfer that snapshot to the offsite location? The main idea of my operation is to offload the active database server.
I think the answer should remain as others might find it interesting.

Comment: True that will be only on primary database - since you **also** want to do modifications. If you use mirroring and go with snapshot on secondary server, it will be read-only. I cant think of anyother way to help in your situation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given your situation and the information presented here, consider the following...

If disk space allows for it, configure your custom log shipping to have 2 databases on the Secondary server that are both constantly restoring logs from the Primary.  The purpose of database A would be for Disaster Recovery purposes and should be left alone so you never endanger your ability to use it in an emergency situation.  Database B would then be used for your purposes described above, where you can bring it online when needed and do as you see fit.  Once finished, restore the necessary full database backup in NORECOVERY mode to get database B back to restoring logs again.

The goal is really to separate out your DR needs from your other needs as the two can be conflicting (as you've seen).  Without knowing the details of your custom log shipping process it's not possible to advise you on how to go about this, but hopefully this helps conceptually with what could be done.